# How can I block scrolling until the loader displays none?

Tags: html, css, web, loader, preloader

I was wondering if there's a way to block the scroll bar until a div and its loader gets to the point of display none. I don't know if this can be done just with html or css. Any advice?

```
 #loader {
    background: #eeeeee;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#loaderInner {
    background:#eeeeee url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/asdfghfdsas/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px 250px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -125px 0px 0px -125px;
}
body#layout #loader {
    display:none;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: You would likely need to achieve this with javascript. The question is broad though. Can you post a specific set of code you are working with?

Comment: maybe a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some simple CSS to prevent scrolling on the page. But you would need to use JS to handle when to apply this class.

**CSS**

```
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely zero reason to qualify the selector. '.loading {...}' is just fine. Better yet... Make it modular '.no-overflow {...}'

Comment: I tried overflow: hidden; and it doesn't seem to work the way I applied it, I updated my question and added the css part of the code. How could I use JavaScript to apply it accurately?

Comment: It works, my mistake was trying to stop the scrolling at the div.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to put loader div with fixed position, so there's no need to hide the scrollbar (which can cause a strange user experience):

```
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    ...
}
```

The div will show while scrolling

In this case you wouldn't need the "body.loading" rule.

Answer (score 0):

The loader scrolling due to the positioning, so we can easily remove the scroll by changing the position css to position:fixed;
it will 100% work.......

```css
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    background: #eeeeee;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this is the best solution to delete the scroll bar while de Loader is display

```
   html, body.loader {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
```

Comment: Not bad info, Just you can use code styling sytax while adding code in question and answer. That make the code more readable and understandable.